# Fetching all pivot table columns via custom pivot type

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a many-to-many relationship where the pivot table has about 20 additional columns. I am using a custom pivot class, and I have successfully set up the code to return an instance of that class when the ->pivot property is accessed on the relation, e.g.

`$supplier->products->pivot` returns the custom pivot class.

However, when wanting to access the data, I can manually define all the individual attributes of the pivot class (which extends Pivot by the way) in the `belongsToMany` relationship like this:

`return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'])`

...But, how can I retrieve all the pivot data of the class without manually defining them as it ties the relationship declaration very close to the class? Is this possible. If not, it's going to make maintainability a PITA! Ideally, it'd be really nice if withPivot just had a flag to get it all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my circumstances, I found it easier to separate all the data into a separate table and model, and add a foreign key in the pivot table to the additional table record. This allows me to use the 'normal' model handling in Laravel and means I don't have to mess around with problems like this!

My use case was a schema of product and supplier with a many-to-many, and each supplier having their own data for the product, namely price, stock, shipping cost / times etc, so I moved all this from the pivot to a SupplierProduct model.

I'll leave this question here, as although this isn't the direct answer to the question (which I fear the answer is 'no'), this is a solution which is viable and can save quite a bit of coding frustration!